# Background Disappearing after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, background

I saw this bug on a Samsung GIII and I was able to replicate it on my a vd.

The background for my action bar disappears after a left menu animation. What's going on to allow this to happen?

**Pictures:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionbarMenuBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/actionbar_button"
            android:clickable="true">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/actionbar_menu"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/div1"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbarMenuBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_divider"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionbarUpdatesBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/actionbar_button"
            android:clickable="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/actionbarUpdatesText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="111"
                android:textColor="#8CFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/actionbar_notify"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/div2"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/actionbarUpdatesBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_divider"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```